# AWS Lambda calling coinapi throws "HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized"

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am trying to call coinapi from aws lambda python to get the price of a bitcoin
I got new API key from coinapi

```
   from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
   import json
   from pprint import pprint

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       pprint('received request: ' + str(event))
       date_input = event['currentIntent']['slots']['Date']
       print(date_input)
       btc_price = get_bitcoin_price(date_input)
       #pprint(dir(urllib.request))


  def get_bitcoin_price(date):
      print('get_bitcoin_price, date = ' + str(date))
      request = Request('https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/ohlcv/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/latest? 
      period_id=1DAY&limit=1&time_start={}'.format(date))
      #pprint(dir(request.add_header))
      request.add_header('X-CoinAPI-Key', 'ACBDCAC9-63DC-4AD8-A72C-FBDB0DB67858')
      response = json.loads(urlopen(request).read())
      return response[0]['price_close']
```

I am getting the Unauthorized error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized",
    "errorType": "HTTPError",
        "requestId": "b4cdc286-4f62-4d57-9bd8-1b2a3c1e47d3",
        "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 9, in lambda_handler\n    
        btc_price = get_bitcoin_price(date_input)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in get_bitcoin_price\n    
        response = json.loads(urlopen(request).read())\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 214, in urlopen\n    
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 523, in open\n    
        response = meth(req, response)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 632, in 
        http_response\n    response = self.parent.error(\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 561, in error\n    
        return self._call_chain(*args)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 494, in _ 
            call_chain\n    result = func(*args)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py\", line 641, in 
        http_error_default\n    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)\n"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check your API key is valid, preferably by using it outside of this code running in AWS Lambda. Also, you appear to be requesting the latest OHLCV data rather than a history. I don't think `time_start` is a supported parameter for a latest query.

Comment: I got the apikey yesterday only. How to test if the api key is working? Thank You for the reply

Comment: Go to wherever your API keys are managed (at the coinapi.io site?) and check if this key has been invalidated. Or make an API request with it using Python requests or Postman or httpie. But do tests from your laptop to take AWS and Lambda out of the equation.